# How can i pick out the word after a string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to pick out the word/phrase (wrapped in hashtags) after a certain string.  For instance:

> This is an example paragraph and I am trying to get the word/phrase after the artist name which is in hash tags, such as  @calvinharris #feel so close#.

Now, I have been able to successfully grab all @words from the string using:

```
preg_match_all('!@(.+)(?:\s|$)!U', $string, $matches)
```

But is there a way I can easily grab the hashtag enclosed phrases (if they're there) after an @name?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regexp:

```
^@(.+)#(.+)#$
```

And if you want to remove spaces

```
^@(.+)\S*#(.+)\S*#$
```

And if you want to trim a lot

```
^@\S*(.+)\S*#\S*(.+)\S*#$
```

And you are not sure there is hashtag (or wathever it is called)

```
^@\S*(.+)\S*(#\S*(.+)\S*#)?$
```

Comment: Why use anchors? The '@' is not at the beginning of the string.

Comment: In his case `@calvinharris #feel so close#` the '@' is at the beginning

Comment: This won't match of there are no hashes in the string.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tweeter hashtag syntax (it's for tweeter right?) So i only took care of the expression Mike gave

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
preg_match_all('/@(\w+)\s?(?:#([^#]+)#)?/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain the "artist name"
`$matches[2]` will contain the optional phrase

Answer (score 1):

Remember to make your character sets as specific as possible:

```
preg_match_all('!@([^\s]+) #([^#]+)#!U', $string, $matches)
```

`[^\s]+` will match up to the first white space, `[^#]+` will match up to the closing hash tag.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick (no / / delimiters included):

```
@(\S+)\s+#(.+?)#
```

"1 or more non-whitespace, followed by 1 or more whitespace, followed by some characters enclosed by #"

Note the use of the non-greedy operator (?) for the text inside the hash.

EDIT:

after `preg_match_all`, $match[1] will correspond to the artist name, $match[2] to the text in hash tags

Comment: This will only match iff the string contains #. They are optional in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make this by using groups and preg_match.

```
$name = "calvinharris";
preg_match('/@'.$name.' #([\w\s]+)#/', "This is an example paragraph and I am trying to get the word/phrase after the artist name which is in hash tags, such as @calvinharris #feel so close#. ", $match);
echo '$match = ' . $match[1]; //feel so close
```

The idea is to use grouping (the things between brackets) and get this group.